# GLSL Shader that displays a Rotating Rainbow Ring

Tags: mathematics, glsl

I'm learning GLSL shaders on Book of Shaders and I decided to mess around with one of the examples. I wanted to see, **whats a more efficient way to calculate to mask out the color?**

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

#define TWO_PI 6.28318530718

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform float u_time;

//  Function from Iñigo Quiles
//  https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MsS3Wc
vec3 hsb2rgb( in vec3 c ){
    vec3 rgb = clamp(abs(mod(c.x*6.0+vec3(0.0,4.0,2.0),6.0)-3.0)-1.0,0.0,1.0);
    rgb = rgb*rgb*(3.0-2.0*rgb);
    return c.z * mix( vec3(1.0), rgb, c.y);
}

void main(){
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution;
    vec3 color = vec3(0.0);

    // Use polar coordinates instead of cartesian
    vec2 toCenter = vec2(0.5)-st;

    float angle = atan(toCenter.y,toCenter.x);
    float radius = length(toCenter)*2.0;

    angle = angle + u_time;

    float outsideMask = 1.0 - step(distance(st, vec2(0.5)), 0.3);
    float insideMask = 1.0 - step(0.2, distance(st, vec2(0.5)));
    float visibleArea = 1.0 - insideMask - outsideMask;

    // Map the angle (-PI to PI) to the Hue (from 0 to 1)
    // and the Saturation to the radius
    color = hsb2rgb(vec3((angle/TWO_PI)+0.5,radius, 1.0));

    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, visibleArea);
}
```

Here is an image of the end result.

[image: End Result.]

The `outsideMask`, `insideMask` and `visibleArea` variables in particular all have that `1.0` minus something, which seems weird to me. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Distance

In both your `step(...)` functions, you are computing `distance(st, vec2(0.5))`.  If you computed this once, and stored this in a local variable, you'd be able to reuse this computed value, which should save time in your shader.

But ... wait a second ...

```
vec2 toCenter = vec2(0.5)-st;
float radius = length(toCenter)*2.0;
```

You've already computed this distance (length, actually), and stored it (doubled) in the local variable `radius`.  We can use this value directly, by doubling your step thresholds:

```
float outsideMask = 1.0 - step(radius, 0.6);
float insideMask = 1.0 - step(0.4, radius);
float visibleArea = 1.0 - insideMask - outsideMask;
```

Or don't multiply the computed radius by 2.0 for the `radius` variable, and multiply it by 2 when you use it to compute the colour:

```
float radius = length(toCenter);

float outsideMask = 1.0 - step(radius, 0.3);
float insideMask = 1.0 - step(0.2, radius);
float visibleArea = 1.0 - insideMask - outsideMask;

color = hsb2rgb(vec3((angle/TWO_PI)+0.5, radius*2.0, 1.0));
```

### visibleArea

1. `outsideMask = 1.0 - step(radius, 0.3)`
2. `insideMask = 1.0 - step(0.2, radius)`
3. `visibleArea = 1.0 - insideMask - outsideMask`

Substituting `insideMask` into (3):

4. `visibleArea = 1.0 - (1.0 - step(0.2, radius)) - outsideMask`
5. `visibleArea = 1.0 - 1.0 + step(0.2, radius) - outsideMask`
6. `visibleArea = step(0.2, radius) - outsideMask`

From `step(A,B) = 1 - step(B,A)`, we can reworking (1) as:

7. `outsideMask = step(0.3, radius)`

And substituting into (6):

8. `visibleArea = step(0.2, radius) - step(0.3, radius)`